# Can I use many external javascript files (<script src="">) for my 24-hour running program?

Tags: javascript

My code snippet is as follows:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
```

I have to run my javascript program for 24 hours on my web server.
My simple questions are:

(1) if the https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com site is suddenly not working, my program does not work even though my web server is currently running?

(2) If so, using the "script src=" is not a good choice for my program? Do I need to copy all of the js files into my local computer to run my program reliably (for 24 hours)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's enough if the site `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com` is working when you start the script. After being retreived, even if the site goes down, your script can go on working for your 24h because it's still loaded. But of course, it's better if you host `socket.io` on your server so that you can start your script any time

Comment: With CDNs you introduce second point of failures. The only advantage CDNs have for the visitor is that they increase the probability that the script is already in the browser cache and does not need to be loaded, so the first visit of your webpage will be faster. After that point there is no advantage anymore, only possible disadvantages. So most of the time it is better to serve all script form your own server,

Answer (score -1):

If you talk about socket.io, this library useless without live connection. Otherwise if you need this for learn opportunities of this library and just want practice, of course i recommend you download this library and all will work always (24h/day).

but you need use script src with local path.

```
<script src="./downloaded/socket.io.min.js"></script>
```

and don't forget start local server for your app.